# Flutter dispose exception

Tags: flutter

Flutter throw me this exception when I exit the screen with pushAndRemoveUntil in future(async) then come back to the screen again.

"Unhandled Exception: This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct).
E/flutter (10962): Consider cancelling any active work during "dispose" or using the "mounted" getter to determine if the State is still active."

This is the flow to produce this exception:
All functions in the APP will call API with future async function then exit the app with pushAndRemoveUntil(logout screen) if the API return 401(not authenticate), user need to re-login again to use the app. When the user login the app again then this exception threw out.

Any idea on how to dispose or handle this? Although the app won't crash but still will throw the exception.

Comment: Are you calling any methods after calling `pushAndRemoveUntil`? Better to post the relevant code.

Comment: Before call `setState` function, you can check `mounted` is true or not.

Comment: @DarShan yup it will throw catcherror after pushAndRemoveUntil but I am able to solve by using mounted just all the function have to check that.